# Plot gradient circles

Tags: r

I am attempting to reproduce a Stephen Few graphic with gradient circles that demonstrates the hard wired assumption that light appears from above.  Here are the circles:

[image]

How can I recreate this?  Drawing the circles isn't too bad but adding gradient is where I get thrown.  I am thinking grid may create something more crisp but this may be a misconception I have.

Here is the start with drawing circles:

```
## John Fox circle function
source("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503/wordpress/circle_fun.txt")

par(mar=rep(1, 4), bg = "grey80")
plot.new()

for (i in seq(0, 1, by = .2)) {
    for (j in seq(.6, 1, by = .1)) {
        circle(i, j, .5, "cm", , 1)
    }
}
```

Related question: [How to use R to build bubble charts with gradient fills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618991/how-to-use-r-to-build-bubble-charts-with-gradient-fills)

**EDIT:**

Thought I'd share the results:
[image]

And [here's the code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503/presentations/data%20visualization/clari_talk.Rmd).

Comment: how smooth do you need the gradient to be?

Comment: Enough to retain the illusion but you can see the lines in the gradient above.

Comment: Perhaps you can create several rows of black-to-white gradients, then plot over them?  This question on gradients:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070101/2d-color-gradient-plot-in-r

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With some repeated use of `clip`, you can get there.

```
# set up a blank plot
par(mar=rep(0, 4))
par(bg="#cccccc")
plot(NA,xlim=0:1,ylim=0:1)

# define a function
grad.circ <- function(centrex,centrey,radius,col,resolution) {
  colfunc <- colorRampPalette(col)
  shades <- colfunc(resolution)

  for (i in seq_along(shades) ) {
   clip(
      centrex - radius,
      centrex + radius,
      (centrey + radius) - ((i-1) * (radius*2)/length(shades)),
      (centrey + radius) - (i     * (radius*2)/length(shades))
       )
   symbols(
     centrex,
     centrey,
     circles=radius,
     bg=shades[i],
     fg=NA,
     add=TRUE,
     inches=FALSE
          )
  }
}

# call the function
grad.circ(0.5,0.5,0.5,c("black", "white"),300)
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT (by Tyler Rinker):**

I wanted to add the rest of the code I used to replicate the image:

```
FUN <- function(plot = TRUE, cols = c("black", "white")) {
    plot(NA, xlim=0:1, ylim=0:1, axes=FALSE)
    if (plot) {
        grad.circ(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, cols, 300)
    }
}

FUN2 <- function(){
    lapply(1:3, function(i) FUN(,c("white", "black")))
    FUN(F)
    lapply(1:3, function(i) FUN())
}


X11(10, 4.5)
par(mfrow=c(3, 7))
par(mar=rep(0, 4))
par(bg="gray70")
invisible(lapply(1:3, function(i) FUN2()))
```

Comment: I've never seen clip used.  I'm trying to extend this.  How can I make the circles smaller?  In other words what is controlling circle radius?

Comment: @TylerRinker - I have generalised the code now so hopefully it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version using rasters and `rasterImage`:

```
image <- as.raster( matrix( seq(0,1,length.out=1001), nrow=1001, ncol=1001) )
tmp <- ( row(image) - 501 ) ^2 + ( col(image) - 501 )^2
image[tmp > 500^2] <- NA

image2 <- as.raster( matrix( seq(1,0, length.out=1001), nrow=1001, ncol=1001) )
image2[ tmp > 500^2 ] <- NA

image3 <- row(image) + col(image)
image3 <- image3/max(image3)
image3[tmp>500^2] <- NA
image4 <- 1-image3
image3 <- as.raster(image3)
image4 <- as.raster(image4)

plot( 0:1, 0:1, type='n', asp=1,ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
rect(0,0,1,1, col='grey')
rasterImage(image, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3)
rasterImage(image2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7)
rasterImage(image3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4)
rasterImage(image4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8)
```

Other directions of shading can be made by changing the math a little.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the (not on CRAN) package `zernike` . It's designed to produce various images related to Zernike polynomials, heavily used in optics & astronomy systems.  Your desired images are pretty much the second Zernike term.

The author is Author: M.L. Peck (mpeck1@ix.netcom.com)  ;  I forget exactly where the R-package resides on hte web.

Comment: Here's the link: http://wildlife-pix.com/rpackages/ but I couldn't apply it to this problem.  And it was built pre R 3.0.0.

Comment: @TylerRinker Thanks for finding it.  I never build it; just use the R-functions included.

Answer (score 2):

And here's an approach using `sp` and `rgeos` (similar application [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432485/489704) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266627/489704)).

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
```

1. Create two sets of 9 circles by buffering points, then plot their union to set up the plotting area.

   ```
   b <- gBuffer(SpatialPoints(cbind(rep(1:3, 3), rep(1:3, each=3))), TRUE, 
                width=0.45, quadsegs=100)
   b2 <- gBuffer(SpatialPoints(cbind(rep(5:7, 3), rep(1:3, each=3))), TRUE, 
                 width=0.45, quadsegs=100)

   plot(gUnion(b, b2), border=NA)
   ```
2. Step through the polygons and extract their bounding boxes.

   ```
   bb <- sapply(b@polygons, bbox)
   bb2 <- sapply(b2@polygons, bbox)
   ```
3. Plot stacked segments to simulate a gradient.

   ```
   segments(rep(bb[1,], each=1000), 
            mapply(seq, bb[2,], bb[4,], len=1000), 
            rep(bb[3,], each=1000), col=gray.colors(1000, 0))

   segments(rep(bb2[1,], each=1000), 
            mapply(seq, bb2[2,], bb2[4,], len=1000), 
            rep(bb2[3,], each=1000), col=rev(gray.colors(1000, 0)))
   ```
4. Difference the union of the `SpatialPolygon` objects and plot the differenced polygon to mask out the non-circles areas.

   ```
   plot(gDifference(as(extent(par('usr')), 'SpatialPolygons'), gUnion(b, b2)), 
        col='gray80', border='gray80', add=TRUE)
   ```
5. For bonus circle smoothness, plot the circles once more, with colour equal to the background colour.

   ```
   plot(gUnion(b, b2), border='gray80', lwd=2, add=TRUE)
   ```

[image: gradient bubbles]

Comment: Looks very promising for smoothness.  Where is the `extent` function from in step 4?

Comment: @Tyler - `raster ` ... Sorry bout that.

Comment: Nice, worked very well and the breakdown was nice too.