# Vertical gradient color with geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have hard time finding a solution for creating gradient color.
This is how it should  look like(dont mind the blue bars)
  [image]

Something similar to  [How to make gradient color filled timeseries plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250542/how-to-make-gradient-color-filled-timeseries-plot-in-r), but a bit to advanced for me to reuse this example. I dont have any negative values and max is 80.I have tried the answer offered by `nograpes`, my PC was frozen for some 6-7 min and then I got message:
`Error in rowSums(na) : 
  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (172440001 of 16 bytes)`

This is only a subset of data with 841 rows (some containing NAs), and solution in previous answer could hardly work for me.

```
    df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1497178800, 1497182400, 1497186000, 
1497189600, 1497193200, 1497196800, 1497200400, 1497204000, 1497207600, 
1497211200, 1497214800, 1497218400, 1497222000, 1497225600, 1497229200, 
1497232800, 1497236400, 1497240000, 1497243600, 1497247200, 1497250800, 
1497254400, 1497258000, 1497261600, 1497265200, 1497268800, 1497272400, 
1497276000, 1497279600, 1497283200, 1497286800, 1497290400, 1497294000, 
1497297600, 1497301200, 1497304800, 1497308400, 1497312000, 1497315600, 
1497319200, 1497322800, 1497326400, 1497330000, 1497333600, 1497337200, 
1497340800, 1497344400, 1497348000, 1497351600, 1497355200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dk_infpressure = c(22, 21.6, 21.2, 
20.9, 20.5, 20.1, 19.8, 19.4, 19, 18.6, 18.2, 17.9, 17.5, 17.1, 
16.8, 16.4, 16, 15.6, 15.2, 14.9, 14.5, 14.1, 13.8, 13.4, 13, 
12.5, 11.9, 11.4, 10.8, 10.3, 9.8, 9.2, 8.7, 8.1, 7.6, 7, 6.5, 
6, 5.4, 4.9, 4.3, 3.8, 3.2, 2.7, 2.2, 1.6, 1.1, 0.5, 0, 0)), .Names = c("date", 
"dk_infpressure"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code to get basic plot:

```
 ggplot()+
geom_area(data=df, aes(x = date, y= dk_infpressure ) )+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 80))
```

Comment: Do you want us to write the code for you? Because the answer is already there you only need to modify to work for datetime objects.

Comment: I have made changes to the question. Please tell me if I can do something more to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Because `geom_area` can't take a gradient fill, it's a somewhat hard problem.

Here's a decidedly hacky but possibly sufficient option that makes a raster (but using `geom_tile` since x and y sizes differ) and covering the ragged edges with cropping and `ggforce::geom_link` (a version of `geom_segment` that can plot a gradient):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    mutate(dk_infpressure = map(dk_infpressure, ~seq(0, .x, .05))) %>%    # make grid of points
    unnest() %>% 
    ggplot(aes(date, dk_infpressure, fill = dk_infpressure)) + 
    geom_tile(width = 3600, height = 0.05) + 
    # hide square tops
    ggforce::geom_link(aes(color = dk_infpressure, xend = lag(date), yend = lag(dk_infpressure)), 
                       data = df, size = 2.5, show.legend = FALSE) + 
    scale_x_datetime(expand = c(0, 0)) +    # hide overplotting of line
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @alistaire! I have a few questions: When I run this on my real data, it gives me error: `Error in seq.default(0, .x, 0.05) : 'to' must be a finite number`. How can I change color to yellow and red gradient? Can ylab be fixed at 80?

Comment: The error is probably because of an `NA` value in `dk_infpressure`. Since it won't plot anyway, you could just call `na.omit` or `tidyr::drop_na` on the whole data.frame before plotting. To change the gradient, use `scale_fill_gradient` and `scale_color_gradient` (or equivalents).