# How to put a scale gradient with specific values to ggplot geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, gradient, fill

I would like to create a barplot with ggplot2 puttingg a scale fill gradient where I can set the values of min, mid and max (in my case it would be: min = 0, mid = 50, max = 100).
For each of these values I'd like to associate a scale gradient where 0 correspond to blue, mid to yellow (or white) and 100 to red.

I found nothing here, could you help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Here there is the code I tried to use but didn't work (the barplot I obtain has has gray bars).

```
TPH <- ggplot(ser, aes(x= Stages, y= TPH))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_gradient(low='blue', high='red')+
  labs(y= expression("Counts per million (CPM)"), x = "Hours post fertilization (hpf)")+
  ggtitle("Tryptophan Hydroxylase", subtitle = "TPH")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5),
        plot.subtitle=element_text(hjust=0.5))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("hpf00" = "0", "hpf04" = "4", "hpf08" ="8", "hpf12"="12", "hpf16"="16", "hpf20"="20","hpf24"="24", "hpf28"="28", "hpf32"="32", "hpf36"="36","hpf40"="40", "hpf44"="44", "hpf48"="48", "hpf52"="52", "hpf72"="72"))
TPH
```

Comment: Hi Beatrice. You'll make it easier for others to answer if you can edit your question to include some of your input data. Please try adding the output of `dput(ser)` or a subset of the data if it's too large to share. One issue that's evident in your `ggplot` function: nothing is being mapped to the `fill` aesthetic.

Comment: `scale_fill_gradient2()` also allows you to set a middle colour.

Comment: Hello Seth and Teunbrand,
thank you a lot for your advices and help!

Cheers,
Beatrice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data looks like this (please include some example data in your next questions)

```r
# libraries
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123) 

# get example data
ser <- data.frame(Stages = c("hpf00", "hpf04", "hpf08", "hpf12", "hpf16",
                                 "hpf20", "hpf24", "hpf28", "hpf32", "hpf36",
                                 "hpf40", "hpf44", "hpf48", "hpf52", "hpf72")) %>%
      mutate(TPH = sample(1:100, length(Stages)))
```

you can generate a vector from 0 to your observation per level of `Stages` (following the answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71043558/15024678). You then unnest these vectors:

```r
ser_mod <- ser %>%
  mutate(TPH = purrr::map(TPH, ~0:.x)) %>%
  unnest_longer(TPH)
```

This can be plotted using `geom_tile()` resulting in a bar chart that fits your description.

```r
ggplot(ser_mod, aes(x = Stages, y = TPH)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = TPH, width = .9)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlBu") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Output:
[image]

### Modified solution if you want to have the bar completely in red if the maximum value per level on the x-axis is 100

Get modified example data so that TPH = 100 for hpf12:

```r
# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123) 

# get example data
ser <- data.frame(Stages = c("hpf00", "hpf04", "hpf08", "hpf12", "hpf16",
                             "hpf20", "hpf24", "hpf28", "hpf32", "hpf36",
                             "hpf40", "hpf44", "hpf48", "hpf52", "hpf72")) %>%
  mutate(TPH = sample(1:100, length(Stages))) %>%
  mutate(TPH = ifelse(Stages == "hpf12", 100, TPH))
```

After generating the column containing values from 0 to the value of your observation per level of `TPH` you can generate a new column (`TPH_fill`) you use for coloring. This column can then be modified so that it only contains 100 (resulting in red color) if the maximum value of `TPH` is 100:

```r
ser_mod <- ser %>%
  mutate(TPH = purrr::map(TPH, ~0:.x)) %>%
  unnest_longer(TPH) %>%
  group_by(Stages) %>%
  mutate(TPH_fill = ifelse(max(TPH) == 100, 100, TPH)) %>%
  mutate(TPH_fill = ifelse(TPH_fill != 100, TPH, TPH_fill))
```

Plot using `TPH_fill` as argument for `fill`:

```r
ggplot(ser_mod, aes(x = Stages, y = TPH)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = TPH_fill, width = .9)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlBu") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Output:
[image]

### Modified solution if you do not want to have the color gradient along the y axis but bars colored by their maximum value

You can plot a `geom_col()` based on the unmodified data and set `fill` by the value of `TPH`:

```r
ggplot(ser, aes(x = Stages, y = TPH)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = TPH)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlBu") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hello!
Thank you a lot for your reply!
Yes, my graph is like the one you put.

Another question: do you know if it's possible to have a bar of just one color? For example: let's assume that at 12 hpf I have 100 (the maximum), could it be possible to have it all fill with red and the others with other shades based on the number?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: @Beatrice, I've added a second example that produces uniformly colored bars if TPH is 100.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your helo, do you know if it's possible to have the same results also for the other bars so that they have just one color? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I have added another example. Is this what you are looking for? This leads away from your original question though so please consider asking a new question if you want further modifications.