# Create top-to-bottom fade/gradient geom_density in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-gradients

I would like to create a `geom_density` that has a top-to-bottom gradient. This is just for aesthetics. For example, the fade of this plot is what I want to achieve:
[image]

**Minimal working example:**

Load libraries:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

Here's some data

```r
dat <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18335, 18336, 18337, 18338, 
                                         18339, 18340, 18341, 18342, 18343, 18344, 18345, 18346, 18347, 
                                         18348, 18349, 18350, 18351, 18352, 18353, 18354, 18355, 18356, 
                                         18357, 18358, 18359, 18360, 18361, 18362, 18363, 18364, 18365, 
                                         18366, 18367, 18368, 18369, 18370, 18371, 18372, 18373, 18374, 
                                         18375, 18376, 18377, 18378, 18379, 18380, 18381, 18382, 18383, 
                                         18384, 18385, 18386, 18387, 18388, 18389, 18390, 18391, 18392, 
                                         18393, 18394, 18395, 18396, 18397, 18398, 18399, 18400, 18401, 
                                         18402, 18403, 18404, 18405, 18406, 18407, 18408, 18409, 18410, 
                                         18411, 18412, 18413, 18414, 18415, 18416, 18417, 18418, 18419, 
                                         18420, 18421, 18422, 18423, 18424, 18425, 18426, 18427, 18428, 
                                         18429, 18430, 18431, 18432, 18433, 18434, 18435, 18436, 18437, 
                                         18438, 18439, 18440, 18441, 18442), class = "Date"),
                      n = c(49L, 
                            121L, 152L, 142L, 137L, 138L, 129L, 144L, 187L, 245L, 337L, 363L, 
                            360L, 374L, 386L, 399L, 404L, 395L, 402L, 398L, 389L, 392L, 409L, 
                            419L, 402L, 389L, 414L, 391L, 388L, 377L, 402L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 
                            395L, 396L, 275L, 386L, 393L, 394L, 322L, 383L, 388L, 397L, 343L, 
                            399L, 384L, 366L, 358L, 375L, 378L, 373L, 368L, 377L, 369L, 352L, 
                            360L, 367L, 363L, 357L, 357L, 347L, 329L, 361L, 340L, 334L, 359L, 
                            335L, 325L, 322L, 297L, 326L, 350L, 323L, 343L, 275L, 232L, 226L, 
                            234L, 222L, 221L, 191L, 204L, 174L, 138L, 76L, 58L, 52L, 32L, 
                            29L, 27L, 21L, 22L, 20L, 13L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -108L),
                 class = c("tbl_df", 
                           "tbl", "data.frame")) %>%
  uncount(n)
```

And this is the `geom_density` I would like to fade:

```r
ggplot(dat,
         aes(date)) +
    geom_density(stat = "density",
                 color = "black",
                 fill = "black",
                 lwd = .75)
```

Here's the plot that the above code produces:
[image]

Comment: Other (non-`ggplot`) alternatives: [How to make gradient color filled timeseries plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250542/how-to-make-gradient-color-filled-timeseries-plot-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is currently supported in vanilla ggplot2. A possible solution would be to have a look at the ggpattern package (https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggpattern) but this wouldn't install at my machine. In R4.1 (in development), this should become much easier.

Here is a homebrew function that slices up the polygon using polyclip, which you can then use to plot the density. You can control how smooth it is by setting `n = ...` and the strength of the fade by setting the alpha scale range. I used different data because I couldn't find the `uncount` function.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(polyclip)
#> polyclip 1.10-0 built from Clipper C++ version 6.4.0

fade_polygon <- function(x, y, n = 100) {
  poly <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
  
  # Create bounding-box edges
  yseq <- seq(min(poly$y), max(poly$y), length.out = n)
  xlim <- range(poly$x) + c(-1, 1)
  
  # Pair y-edges
  grad <- cbind(head(yseq, -1), tail(yseq, -1))
  # Add vertical ID
  grad <- cbind(grad, seq_len(nrow(grad)))
  
  # Slice up the polygon
  grad <- apply(grad, 1, function(range) {
    # Create bounding box
    bbox <- data.frame(x = c(xlim, rev(xlim)),
                       y = c(range[1], range[1:2], range[2]))
    
    # Do actual slicing
    slice <- polyclip::polyclip(poly, bbox)
    
    # Format as data.frame
    for (i in seq_along(slice)) {
      slice[[i]] <- data.frame(
        x = slice[[i]]$x,
        y = slice[[i]]$y,
        value = range[3],
        id = c(1, rep(0, length(slice[[i]]$x) - 1))
      )
    }
    slice <- do.call(rbind, slice)
  })
  # Combine slices
  grad <- do.call(rbind, grad)
  # Create IDs
  grad$id <- cumsum(grad$id)
  return(grad)
}

dens <- density(faithful$eruptions)
grad <- fade_polygon(dens$x, dens$y)

ggplot(grad, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(alpha = value, group = id),
               fill = "blue") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: beautiful, thank you! Any way to ensure that the polygon goes all the way down to zero rather than just filling the exact shape of the density curve? (as in the default behavior of geom_density()

Comment: Yes you could replace `yseq <- seq(min(poly$y), max(poly$y), length.out = n)` with `yseq <- seq(0, max(poly$y), length.out = n)` and that should do the trick I think (not tested).

Comment: Hmmm, padding the polygon's edges maybe? `grad <- fade_polygon(c(dens$x[1], dens$x, dens$x[length(dens$x)]), c(0, dens$y, 0))` (tested, but couldn't see difference)

Comment: Just got linked to this from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70235633/7941188). nice answer. I am sure the obscure function is `tidyr::uncount` ... :)

Answer (score 0):

As @teunbrand mentioned, the [ggpattern](https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggpattern) package does provide a solve for this. You'll simply use the `geom_density_pattern` function, setting `pattern = "gradient"` like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = date)) + 
  geom_density_pattern(pattern = "gradient")
```

[image: density plot with gradient]